# Django: Cannot import 'Pages'. Check that 'apps.Pages.apps.PagesConfig.name' is correct

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-signals

I'm trying to load a signal every time the app gets loaded. *(I'm watching a tutorial and I have to do it like that don't ask me why)*
In the tutorial the guy edits the **init**.py file of the app like follows:
`default_app_config = 'payment.apps.PaymentConfig'`

Now my Problem:
I put all my apps in a subfolder "apps" for more overview in my project.
So thought I have to write that line like follows:
`default_app_config = 'apps.Pages.apps.PagesConfig'`
(My app is called Pages)
If I try it I get the error in the title.
I also tried to just write: `Pages.apps.Pagesconfig` but this didn't work either.

I'm open for any ideas. Tanks